# Updating Magento Order Status using API but order goes back to processing

Tags: magento2, orders, order-status

We are updating order statuses using the Magento API.

It shows that the status has been updated in the order status history but the order status still says processing.

Any ideas on this or how to debug?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a couple of months ago.

First please make sure that the status / state relations are correct under

STORES => Order Status

if that is the case, make sure that on the body of your api call you always pass the state with the status (yeah it's weird):

**/index.php/rest/V1/orders**

```
{
    "entity": 
    {
        "entity_id": order id, 
        "state": "state",
        "status": "status"
    }
}
```